# Elegant way to complete a parallel operation on two arrays of unequal lengths

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, numba

I want to write a function in `numba` that runs a math operation on 2 arrays, and accommodate for when both arrays don't have the same element count.

So for example: lets say I want a function that adds each element of array `a` to the elements of array `b` with these 3 possible scenarios:

1) Both `a` and `b` have the same number of items, do `c[ii]=a[ii]+b[ii]`

2) `a` has more items than `b`: do `c[ii]=a[ii]+b[ii]` until `b`'s upper limit, and complete with `c[ii]=a[ii]+b[-1]`

3) `a` has fewer items than `b`: do `c[ii]=a[ii]+b[ii]` until `a`'s upper limit, and complete with `c[ii]=a[-1]+b[ii]`

For this I wrote the code below, which works fine and is fast when dealing with millions of values, but I can clearly see three nearly identical code blocks which feel terribly wasteful. Plus the `if/else` running in a loop also feels terrible.

```
from numba import jit, float64, int32

@jit(float64[:](float64[:], float64[:]), nopython=True)
def add(a, b):

    # Both shapes are equal: add between a[i] and b[i]
    if a.shape[0] == b.shape[0]:
        c = np.empty(a.shape)

        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i]

        return c

    # a has more entries than b: add between a[i] and b[i] until b.shape[0]-1 is reached.
    # finish the loop with add between a[i] and b[-1]
    elif a.shape[0] > b.shape[0]:
        c = np.empty(a.shape)
        i_ = b.shape[0]-1 # upper limit of b's shape

        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            if i < b.shape[0]:
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
            else:
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i_]

        return c

    # b has more entries than a: add between a[i] and b[i] until a.shape[0]-1 is reached.
    # finish the loop with add between a[-1] and b[i]    
    else:
        c = np.empty(b.shape)
        i_ = a.shape[0]-1 # upper limit of a's shape

        for i in range(b.shape[0]):
            if i < a.shape[0]:
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
            else:
                c[i] = a[i_] + b[i]

        return c
```

I'm new to `numba` and `jit` python code compilation so this may just be "the most efficient way" to do what I want.

But if there is a more elegant way to do this without sacrificing speed I would love to know how.

Comment: `if/else` in a loop is normal in compiled `c` style code.  It's only bad in a pure Python context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overnight I realized that what I could do is clip the indices on the fly:

```
@njit(float64[:](float64[:], float64[:]))
def add_clamped(a,b):
    # Find the maximum indices to use for clipping purposes
    max_a, max_b = a.shape[0]-1, b.shape[0]-1
    maxsize = max(a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
    c = np.empty(maxsize)    

    # Run throught the arrays and clip indices on the fly
    for idx in range(maxsize):
        idx_a = min(idx, max_a)
        idx_b = min(idx, max_b)

        # Do some crazy expensive math here
        c[idx] = a[idx_a] + b[idx_b]    

    return c
```

As a test I compared algorithms over 10 million entries and here are the results:

```
add_original:  0.01952 seconds
add_MSeifert:  0.02058 seconds
add_clamped:   0.02562 seconds
```

So not as fast as @MSeifert's answer, but keeps the code to 1 loop and keeps all the core math in one place (for when doing more complex than adding 2 arrays).

Answer (score 1):

> but I can clearly see three nearly identical code blocks which feel terribly wasteful.

Yes, you're repeating yourself a lot in the code. On the other hand it's very easy to see what each case does.

You could simply use two loops instead:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:]))
def add2(a, b):
    size1, size2 = a.shape[0], b.shape[0]
    maxsize, minsize = max(size1, size2), min(size1, size2)
    c = np.empty(maxsize)

    # Calculate the elements which are present in a and b
    for idx in range(minsize):
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx]

    # Check which array is longer and which fillvalue should be applied
    if size1 > size2:
        missing = a
        filler = b[-1]
    else:
        missing = b
        filler = a[-1]

    # Calculate the elements after a or b ended. In case they have equal lengths
    # the range is of length 0 so it won't enter.
    for idx in range(minsize, maxsize):
        c[idx] = missing[idx] + filler

    return c
```

A lot less repetition, but maybe not as clear.

> Plus the `if`/`else` running in a loop also feels terrible.

Actually it's not as bad as it seems because branch prediction makes this `if` very cheap. It will be `True` as long as both arrays still have elements and only switches to `False` (and stays `False` thereafter) when one array is exhausted. That's very easy for your computer to predict so this check will be very cheap (almost for free).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Last night it occurred to me that I could also clip the indices on the fly. I added the code to my question, let me know what you think.

Comment: @Fnord You probably should add that as another answer. That's also a clever idea but I would do the `max` outside of the loop and just do the `min` inside.

Comment: done! Also you made me realize `max` wasn't needed at all.